# Default password for MYSQL database for Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to containerize my Laravel application using `Laravel Sail` is it was up and running.

There is two running container one for application and another for mysql.

[image]

And i trying to access mysql container to view the data inside it. So i using this `docker exec -it 480c  mysql -uroot -p` command to access it from my `wsl2`. But i prompt me to enter password.

But i didn't set mysql database password inside my `.env` file.

Here is my .env file:

[image]

Is't any default password for the mysql database? Or any other ways to access mysql database running in `wsl`?

Thanks.l

Comment: try `password` as password

Comment: try root  as password

Comment: Why are you using `mysql -u root -p` (I assumed it was a typo and not actually -uroot)? Parameter -p literally means "I want to pass a password". Is using `mysql -u root` not an option? What happens if you just press enter with `-p` being present?